# C++ sparse matrix container

Tags: c++, matrix, boost, sparse-matrix

I need a container to store sparse matrix. the size of the matrix is about 20,000*3,000,000. But there are gaps, so the actual matrix is about 20,000*500,000. And only 1% of the actual matrix is occupied.

I need to keep the index, something like 2D array. But 2D array is not able to fit the entire datasets into memory. I found boost library that has `mapped_matrix`, `compressed_matrix`, `coordinate_matrix`.

I wonder what are the differences? Couldn't figure out from [their documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.html).

And is there any other standard libraries that has a sparse matrix container and can be accessed by using indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

`sparse_matrix`: This type is an implementation of a std::map >. Thus insertion of an element takes O(log(M)+log(K)) operations plus storage allocation, which should be (amortized) contant time. The disadvantage is slower traversal throug all elements, some levels of indirection (pointers) and noncontiguous storage.

`compressed_matrix`: This type is an implementation of the compressed row storage known from Netlib (www.netlib.org) widely used by FORTRAN linear algebra libraries. Short: We have a vector of values, a vector of column indices corresponding to this values and a vector of pointers where each row starts. Inserting one element takes O(log(M)+log(K)) operation plus O(M*K) storage operations if the values and column indices have to be moved one position. Adding elements in order by push_back(i,j,value) is constant time. Increasing an existend element takes only O(log(M)+log(K)) Operations. The advantage is very fast element traversal which gives optimal performance for linear algebra routines.

`coordinate_matrix`: This type is an implementation a list of triples (i,j,value) by using three vectors. Therefore you can insert elements in random order by insert(i,j,value) which acts like A(i,j) += value. This actually differs from insert operations for other matrix types. The price you pay is a sort() operation before each element access and additional storage if you insert many elements more than once. sort() sorts all elements and combines multiple insertions of an element to one. Thus insertion of an element is constant time plus one sort() at the end for O(M*K *log(M*K)) operations depending on the method. (According to Stroustrup, "C++": std::sort() has average O(n*log(n)), worst case O(n*n), std::stable_sort() has O(n*log(n)*log(n)) plus O(n*log(n)) storage.) For this type linear algebra operations are typically slower than for compressed_matrix.

reference: http://www.guwi17.de/ublas/matrix_sparse_usage.html

Hope this will help you if you have the same problem reading their document.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [overview page of uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.html). They describe the storage used by the sparse vectors and matrices there.

Answer (score 0):

Look At 
1.(eigen)http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/
2.(ublas)http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.html
3.(MTL4)

Depends on your requirement use any one of them,probably go through **ublas** they describe the storage used by the sparse vectors and matrices there.